# Remove broken spark plug threads

Tags: ford, sparkplugs, tools, ka

So somehow, one of the spark plugs popped out while I was driving along. The thread snapped from the bolt and is now stuck. Is there a way to get the thread out without damaging the engine? Bare in mind that anything used to loosen it will pour into the spark chamber. I should add that the thread and bolt are highly rusted and the thread is very stuck in place.

Not very technical on this, so the name of any tools or lubricant needed would be very helpful.

Many thanks.

Comment: Hey, you might want to check out [this post](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/234/what-is-the-proper-way-to-extract-a-broken-sparkplug).  Welcome to mechanics.SE!

Comment: In order to be able to give any accurate advice, we need to know what make and model of car and what engine it has.

Comment: Sorry, it's a 1.3 52 plate ford ka.

Comment: Thanks anonymous2, I will try a screw extractor. As for the penetrating oil, is it ok if some were to get into the spark chamber?

Comment: Penetrating oil will burn off when you start your engine.  You don't want frequent shots in your engine (it would create deposits), but for a maintenance purpose like this, I would just recommend a particularly flammable one like WD-40 or something.  **MAKE SURE THE ENGINE ISN'T STILL HOT!**  WD-40 and a lot of penetrating oils are explosive.